# android multiple screen design which one is best ,whether creating multiple layout or using design

Tags: android

which is best method multiple screen or dimension  ?

Answer (score 1):

As always: it depends on the situation :)

Some layouts can be simply designed to fit all screen variations and this is nice, because changes to them are pretty easy, as you only have one file.

Most of the layouts I have seen so far can't be disigned to work on every screen variation. For them you have to provide multiple layout files for the different screens. For reducing the effort of changes in this layout files, you should try to extract the parts of your layouts that stay the same for every variation and use includes in your screen size specific layout files.